# Why is the word "tzvi" ambiguous?

Tags: hebrew, translation, animals

The word *tsvi* (צבי) is traditionally considered to mean "deer". For example, the Hebrew name "Tsvi" has the Yiddish equivalent "Hersh", and "Hirsch" means "deer" in German.

On the other hand, in Israel the word *tsvi* is used to mean "antelope", while deer are called *eyal* (איל). (At least, by people who deal with nature and animals.)

Why this discrepancy?

Comment: The word Tzvi also means "want" as you can see in the last Posuk of the Akdamus of Shavuos.

Comment: It also means "Glory".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common mistake. No deep reason.
b.t.w I think the error is not in Hebrew, but rather in the translation of Hirsh to Tzvi

Comment: Is this also true of _nesher_ (eagle / vulture)?

Comment: Yes.  Ask any Israeli what a nesher is, and they will tell you its a ugly looking bird that eats dead things :)   It's a problem of having limited access to animals in Europe, and aesthetic issues.

Answer (score 5):

[R. Natan Slifkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natan_Slifkin) discusses this in a number of places. In [one such place](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2011/07/there-are-no-kangaroos-in-tehillim.html) he writes:

> This is no different from how the Rishonim in Ashkenaz mistakenly
>   thought that the tzvi is the deer, and were therefore confounded by
>   the Gemara which states that the horns of a tzvi are not branched. The
>   reason was that that they were unfamiliar with the gazelle, which does
>   not live in Europe, and so transposed the name tzvi to the deer. Only
>   Rav Saadiah Gaon, who was familiar with the animal life of the Middle
>   East, correctly identified the tzvi as the gazelle and the ayal as the
>   deer—and he likewise correctly identifies the shafan as al-wabr.

Answer (score 0):

The horn of a tzvi is kosher for making a shofar.  Deer do not have horns; they have antlers and couldn't possibly be used as a shofar.  Therefore a tzvi cannot be a deer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you made known your source for the horn of a tzvi being kosher for making a shofar

Comment: ...and for your claim that antlers "couldn't possibly be used as a shofar".

Comment: ...and for your implied claim that _tz'vi_ meant the same thing at the time the _shofar_ rule's source was written as it did at the time the name was paired with _hirsch_. Languages change over time.

Comment: Not exactly an adequate source, but the first two pages of this slifkin article touches on these issues. http://zootorah.com/assets/media/essays/ExoticShofars.pdf